# Drupal 7 selectively update LIVE site from DEV

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7, translation, updating

My client has a LIVE site which is translated into 2 languages. For this they are using the Entity Translate module.

**The issue is the same site has been recreated on a DEV server and the translations has increased by one more language.
Meanwhile, the LIVE site has been updated quite a lot so it is not possible to overwrite with the DEV site's database.**

Can anyone give me some tips on how to manage updating the LIVE site with the new language translation from the DEV without causing any issues?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a module like [Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) to export the new nodes from your live site and import them into the dev site. Then you could use [Backup and Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) to migrate the dev site back out to live.